# TypeError: process_spider_output() got multiple values for keyword argument 'response'

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy spider middle ware class like this

```
class SaveSpiderMidlleWare:
    """ This is a middleware class which handles all the operations of  saving the spider response data into flat file """

    def  process_spider_output(response, result, spider):
        print("Response :",response.url)
        return response
```

Which is returning this error

```
TypeError: process_spider_output() got multiple values for keyword argument 'response'
```

On triggering  crawl spider

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def  process_spider_output(response, result, spider):
```

should be

```
 def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
```

this method is method of middleware object, and object methods in python always take reference to object as first parameter. [Docs for this method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.spidermiddlewares.SpiderMiddleware.process_spider_output) don't include `self` param probably assuming that its existence is obvious.